# Can I specify multiple keys to nested dictionary on single for loop rather than using nested for loops?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
d = {names: {IDs: {"constant": value, "some_list": []}}
```

Where each name potentially has multiple IDs, and each ID has a constant value and a list of variable length with specific strings as keys. My goal is to print names and IDS when the list is a given length. I know how to do this with nested for loops:

```
for n in d:
    for i in d[n]:
        num = len(d[n][i]["some_list"])
        if num > 5:
            print "Warning %s %s has %i items" % (n, i, num)
```

I do not have a reason why the above is not acceptable, it works and is readable.

I'm curious though if there is a way to specify n and i on a single for loop. The following fail for different reasons:

```
for one in d.values().keys():  # fails as list has no attribute keys
for one.keys() in d.values():  # fails as functions can't be assigned to calls
```

The following will generate a list of tuples that could then be iterated over, but still contains two for loops inside the comprehension and would require an additional loop through the new list to print:

```
new_list = [(n, i) for n in d for i in d[n] if len(d[n][i]["some_list"] > 5]
```

Is it impossible to do without using 2 for loops? or is there a trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 2+ level dictionary, you are always going to have nested loops somewhere, whether they're hidden inside a function or expressed explicitly.

What you may want to do is change the structure of your dictionary to make it use a multi-part key (in a tuple):

```
tupleDict = { (name,idx):content for name,idd in d.items() for idx,content in idd() }

print(tupleDict)

# {('name1', 'ID11'): {'constant': 1, 'some_list': [1]}, ('name1', 'ID12'): {'constant': 2, 'some_list': [2]}, ...}
```

Then, you can apply filters without nested loops using that alternate structure:

```
min5Lists = { k:v for k,v in tupleDict.items() if len(v['some_list'])>5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of problems here.  First, your syntax is incorrect.

```
d = {names: {IDs: {"constant": value, "some_list": []}}
```

should be more like

```
d = {"names": {"IDs": {"constant": "some_value", "some_list": []}}}
```

If each name can have multiple IDs, and there can be multiple names, show a more complete example:

```
d = {
   "name1": {
      "id1": {"constant": "value1", "some_list": []},
      "id2": {"constant": "value2", "some_list": []},
      },
   "name2": {
      "idA": {"constant": "valueA", "some_list": []},
      "idB": {"constant": "valueB", "some_list": []},
      },
}
```

Since you have an arbitrary set of IDs inside arbitrary set of names, I don't thin it can be done with one loop.

If you could do it in one loop, it would be very difficult to understand and maintain.